# Spring Autowired in Controller not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am very new to Spring and I am writing Web Service using Spring RESTApi ,I have created Model as Product and Controller as Main , I have declared reference of Product in Main controller , but I am getting following exception , why ? Please help me to resolve this..

```
@Controller
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private Product product;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/product/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody
    Product getProoduct(@PathVariable long id) {

        //Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(id);
        product.setOwnerName("Android");
        product.setProductName("Gah");

        return product;
    }

}

public class Product {

    private long id;

    private String productName;

    private String ownerName;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getOwnerName() {
        return ownerName;
    }

    public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
    }
}
```

Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.jaxdepot.restful.controllers.Main" >
        <property name="product" ref="product"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="product" class="com.jaxdepot.restful.models.Product">
        <property name="id" value="45"/>
        <property name="productName" value="androidTab"/>
        <property name="ownerName" value="xyz"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/restful-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.addDefaultAttributes(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2943)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2060)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:242)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:389)
    ... 22 more

Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/restful-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'base-package' must appear on element 'context:component-scan'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.addDefaultAttributes(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2943)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2060)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:242)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:389)
    ... 22 more

Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SpringRestfulWebServiceDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 26 21:13:57 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 26 21:13:57 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5484)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 26 21:13:57 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5484)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Nov 26, 2013 9:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5484)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/restful-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Your structure is a bit weird. Product looks like an entity object, but the way you have it, it will be a singleton bean, i.e. all requests will access the same instance of Product.

Comment: I have commented Product product = new Product(); if I remove comment , it will work very fine ,I don't want to make product object as singleton but I am deliberately doing Autowired just to check Autowired works in such cases or not .

Comment: You can edit your question to add any new details.

Answer (score 3):

You must specify a `base-package` attribute for `<component-scan>`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.name" />
```

This is a restriction given by the `context` namespace XSD at  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd`. It doesn't make sense to component scan *nothing*.

Also, `<context:annotation-config>` is redundant if your specify the above. Get rid of it.

Note that you have other problems. For instance

```
<bean class="com.jaxdepot.restful.controllers.Main" >
    <property name="product" ref="product"/>
</bean>
```

will fail because you don't have a setter for `product` property. Also, because of `@Controller`, if your `component-scan` is setup to to scan the package `Main` is in, you will end up with 2 beans of type `Main` in your context. This might not be something you want. Decide between `@Component` scanning and explicit `<bean>` declarations.

**Note also that, unless you have a servlet context that you aren't showing us, the `@Controller` won't be registered anywhere to process requests.** You don't have a `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element to configure the MVC environment.

Comment: I just need to make create object of product though xml , you can see commented part in Main.getProduct() if I remove comment code will work fine , but I need to create object only from xml file .. what should changes should I do ?

Comment: @Ani Code will most definitely not work fine. What don't you understand about my answer? Go see the exception you are getting. It's pretty clear. Creating a bean is not difficult, you can just specify a `<bean>` like you do. It's how you use it that is difficult.

Comment: <bean class="com.jaxdepot.restful.controllers.Main" >
        <property name="product" ref="product"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="product" class="com.jaxdepot.restful.models.Product">
        <property name="id" value="45"/>
        <property name="productName" value="androidTab"/>
        <property name="ownerName" value="xyz"/>
    </bean> If I remove above from my restful-servlet.xml and remove comment on Product product = new Product() from getProduct() in controller it is working fine , but I want to initialize Product  object from restful-servlet.xml only , what should I do ?